# Git: how to show the diff from a point in history to the current working set?

Tags: git

How do I compute the diff between some point in my git commit history and my current working set?

`git diff` shows me the diff between my working set and `HEAD`.

`git diff origin/master..HEAD` shows me the diff between `origin/master` and `HEAD`.

I'd like to get the union of those two commands, all in one patch file. Is such a thing possible? Currently, I'm emulating it by creating two patch files, which is not satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff abc123` will show you differences between your current working directory and the specified commit (abc123 in this case) (you can also use a branch name here).

From `git help diff`:

```
git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree 
       relative to the named <commit>. You can use HEAD to compare
       it with the latest commit, or a branch name to compare with the 
       tip of a different branch.
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I read right over that without grokking it.